# Forest: Edge at leftmost character

Tags: forest

I am trying to write a join-tree in forest like this:

```
\begin{forest}
[$\bowtie_{p_{AB}}$
    [A]
    [B]
]
\end{forest}
```

However, the Bowtie / join symbol is not centered, and instead the edges seem to spawn from the 'p'.

[image: Non-centered join operator]

I'm probably missing a simple `for tree {}` command but I cannot seem to figure out which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edges from your root node are going from south coordinate of root node. If I understand you correctly, you like that they start from center of `\bowtie` simbol, i.e. they start should be shifted to the left.
One way, how to achieve this is use `\mathrlap` defined in `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {inner ysep=1pt,
            math content,
            }
[\bowtie_{\mathrlap{p_\mathit{AB}^{}}}
    [A]
    [B]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

**Edit:**

Considered @egreg's comment the centering of `\bowtie` is even better:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {inner ysep=1pt,
            math content,
            }
[\bowtie_{\mathrlap{p_\mathit{AB}^{}}\kern-\scriptspace}
    [A]
    [B]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, `\mathrlap` seems to be what I searched for.

Comment: You can even cover your tracks better with `\bowtie_{\mathrlap{p_\mathit{AB}^{}}\kern-\scriptspace}`. Compare the results and see.

Comment: @egreg, you are right. with added kerning `\bowtie` is better centered.